# Escolher caminho index

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core

Olá, estou com um projeto .NET Core Razor.

A minha página `index` está dentro da pasta `Pages`, e eu gostaria de colocar a minha página `index` dentro da pasta Teste que esta dentro da pasta pages, como por exemplo `Pages/Teste`.

Alguém aí sabe como eu posso fazer isso?

E se eu quiser mudar o nome dessa pasta `Pages`, como eu faço para funcionar devidamente?

**ESTRUTURA:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Samuel, poste o código da classe `Startup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisar especificar a pagina no mecanismo de visualização Razor que fica no arquivo Startup.cs, configure o método ConfigureServices dessa forma e deve funcionar:

```
 services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("", "Pages/Teste");
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Este "Teste" aí seria a página, certo? Então no caso deveria ser, por exemplo, Teste.cshtml?

Comment: ja consegui, funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado

Comment: Show meu amigo, feliz em poder lhe ajudar =D 0/

Answer (score 0):

Essa configuração por padrão (ou seja, o `RootDirectory` está configurado para a pasta `/Pages`) e configura suas páginas estão dentro da pasta `/Pages` e segue uma convenção onde as sub-pastas tem o nome da rota para carregar as paginas. Se mudar a `index` para o caminho `Pages/Teste` no navegador também deve ser chamado assim porque segue essa *convenção de nomes de pastas*, exemplo:

```
http://localhost/teste/index
```

para que o carregamento dessa página seja efetuado. Se quiser criar além disso uma rota então faça como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()                
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {           
            // faz a rota para a página padrão
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Teste/index", "");
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

e no navegador:

```
http://localhost
```

seguindo a mesma da configuração padrão, mas, organizado de outra forma.

---

E se eu quiser mudar o nome dessa pasta Pages, como eu faço para funcionar devidamente?

Se alterar o nome da pasta precisa também configurar as opções padrões da seguinte maneira:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{   
    services.AddMvc()                
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            //configurando o nome da pasta root padrão
            options.RootDirectory = "/Pages1";
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

onde `options.RootDirectory` habilita a configurar o nome da pasta padrão das suas páginas.

Todas as duas mudanças sem um contexto e talvez até sem necessidade não trará nenhum beneficio, tente trabalhar com o modo padrão que vai simplificar o seu ambiente de desenvolvimento.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Convenções de rota e aplicativo das Páginas do Razor no ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Ótima explicação. Obrigado pela resposta.